# Read the storage from content script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

For some reason the `log` message is never fired from this content script (`test.js`):

```
var myData = await browser.storage.local.get();
console.log("ok");
```

It seems that it stuck for some reason with `await` and never continue the executing again. And I see no errors or so in the dev tools. The same blocking read from the background script works just fine.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["test.js"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. It works for me. I got the "Ok" message on both the browser console and on the console.

Comment: @SukanyaPurushothaman what firefox version did you use?

Comment: Am using Firefox 67.0.2.